# Why Scaffold-DbContext doesn't put set method set inside relational tables entity class

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When I used Scaffold-DbContext in EF Core 6, the entity Classes created with **set** enabled :

```
public class Employee
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string? LastName { get; set; } 
                                                             
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDatils> EmployeeDatils{ get; set; }
}
```

But in EF Core 7, the entity Classes created without **set** :

```
public class Employee
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string? LastName { get; set; } 
                                                             
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDatils> EmployeeDatils { get;} = new List<EmployeeDatils>();
}
```

So, I can't put data in EmployeeDatils Class. Because it is read-only property and it created only with **get;** method.

And also, I use this code to scaffold :

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=myIP; UID=myUser; Password=myPassword;Database=myDB;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer –OutputDir Db -NoPluralize -UseDatabasenames -f
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `I can't put data in EmployeeDatils Class.` that's a wrong assumption. `.Add` works just fine. So does `AddRange`. There's nothing to fix

Comment: Using `virtual ICollection<EmployeeDatils>` typically means you intend to use lazy loading. In that case, `EmployeeDatils` will be an internal proxy class that can load entities as needed, not the `List<EmployeeDatils>` shown in the code. When you load an `Employee` EF Core will return its own derived class that overrides all virtual lazily loaded collections and replace them with proxy accessors

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos all of these true. But I have a big and enterprise project which programmed using Web Api .NetFramwork and I want to change it to .Net Core Web Api whiteout changing architect. And there are many classes that programmed with this shape :  ```(Employee.EmployeeDetails = myList;)``` . So I have to use this shape.

Comment: Don't use this. Or change the scaffolded code. .NET Core isn't .NET Framework, it's a **very** different runtime. ASP.NET Core has very, very little in common with ASP.NET Framework Web API. `without changing architecture` you have to.

Comment: DI is different, configuration is different, hosting is different, EF Core is different, authentication is different. There's a 10 year gap between ASP.NET Framework Web API and .NET 6. EF Core 6 isn't the same as Entity Framework 6.2 ported to Core, it's a completely different ORM, 6 versions *after* EF 6.2

Comment: Yes , I know. This is my company project and I as a developer can't change that. Because we have short time. And something crashed in our project. Also, the project is very sensitive. So my team and I have to change it in short time.

Comment: You can't make Earth flat by wishing it. No company can. `The project is very sensitive` then don't try to hack it

Comment: If you can't do a proper migration you can use [the .NET Core version of Entity Framework, 6.4.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.4.4#readme-body-tab). Note that this is only meant to assist in short-term migration. There hasn't been a new EF 6 release since 2020.

Comment: There are big differences between EF Core 6 and EF 6 which can lead to nasty surprises. Some features are still not supported in EF Core. Others work differently. Some, like EDMX were removed completely. [The EF/EF Core comparison page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/) shows most of the differences. If you're under time pressure it's better to not try to migrate the ORM along with the rest of the application, or use EF Core only when needed eg to store ASP.NET Core Identity account information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the T4 templates to change this to a not recommended pattern.

see explanation from the EF Core team [here](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/issues/1587#issuecomment-1344808549)

Comment: The OP is trying to migrate a Web API project from Framework straight to .NET 6. I suspect it's better to leave the ORM migration for vNext

Comment: @erikej Let me check it. It is confusing a little that how to use that.

Comment: @ErikEJ I understood this and I installed this extension. But I couldn't use this. I add my tables and dbcontext using this extension. But there is no different with simple scaffold-common. So in this condition I have that issue too.

Comment: You have to  add t4 code templates and customize them - feel free to post an issue in the Github repo for the tool

Comment: @ErikEJ I watched this video on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUexkGWErNk. It helped me. This extension is very useful. And also I have another issue which I have a table that related with own. Scaffold make 2 class from it. How can I fix it?

Comment: I'd still advise you to *not* try migrating from EF 6 to EF Core 6 at the same time as the rest of the project. Juggling 3 balls in the air is easier than 4, and the differences between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core are big enough already. Get the Web API services to run first, then try to migrate from EF 6 to EF Core 6